# Animated color transition

Tags: swift, xcode

Hi this is a more general question on how to approach this. 
As you can see in the image below I have 4 textLabels in a stack view, and behind the stack view is a red UIVew.

When the UIView slides over the next text, I would like the text to change color whenever the view is over the text. 
I don't want an abrupt change, but rather a masking/sliding color effect, driven by the red UIView.

Currently its only changing colours once the transition is done.

How would you approach this?

[image]

on request the basic sliding code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if isScrolling {
        let factor = (scrollView.contentOffset.x/UIScreen.main.bounds.width) * (margin.left/2)
        self.navigationBar.indicatorConstraint.constant = (scrollView.contentOffset.x / 4) - factor
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to check if the middle of x position of the red one is in middle of label width and then change the font color? Do you mind to put some code to be better to understand how it is working?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve but it is not straight forward.

You would have to add white and black text UILabels. These labels contained on a view, for example the *WhiteLabelsView* and the *BlackLabelsView*. The red view should [mask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622557-mask) the WhiteLabelsView, and the BlackLabelsView should be behind them.

Your view should look like this (RedView is the top most view):

- [ RedView ]
- [ WhiteLabelsView ]
- [ BlackLabelsView ]

Comment: Uh! that sounds interesting! I will give this a shot! And post my results. Makes actually sense